# Python script is not returning EC2 instance IDs properly

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a python script that is trying to get every `EC2` instance ID in every AWS account that I own. I am using a custom library (`nwmaws`) that will list every account ID for me. I am using a function that generates an `sts` token and pulls each account id and interpolates the id to dynamically build the `ARN` so I can assume a role in each account and get the instance IDs. I am able to generate the `sts` tokens, but I am not getting the instance IDs in the response. Just an `HTTP 200` status code. Below is my code and the response.

`CODE:`

```
import boto3 
import nwmaws

client = boto3.client('ec2')
accounts = nwmaws.Accounts().list()

def get_sts_token(**kwargs):
    role_arn = kwargs['RoleArn']
    region_name = kwargs['RegionName']
    sts = boto3.client(
        'sts',
        region_name=region_name,
    )
    token = sts.assume_role(
        RoleArn=role_arn,
        RoleSessionName='GetInstances',
        DurationSeconds=900,
    )
    return token["Credentials"]

def get_all_instances():
    for i in accounts:
        account_list = i.account_id
        role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::{}:role/ADFS- 
        GlobalAdmins".format(account_list)

        get_sts_token(RoleArn=role_arn, RegionName="us-east-1")

        response = client.describe_instances()
        print(response)

get_all_instances()
```

`RESPONSE:`

```
{'Reservations': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '5c1e8326-5a36- 
4866-9cfd-bd83bff62d05', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': 
{'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 
'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'date': 'Sun, 13 May 2018 
21:23:25 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
{'Reservations': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '1e165d98-0b5c- 
4172-8917-bf688afbad7c', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': 
{'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '230', 
'date': 'Sun, 13 May 2018 21:23:25 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 
'RetryAttempts': 0}}
{'Reservations': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'e18526d5-c7e9- 
465f-a1fd-87e1d652e95c', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': 
{'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 
'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'date': 'Sun, 13 May 2018 
21:23:25 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}} etc. etc...
```

`DESIRED RESPONSE:`

```
i-xxxxxx
i-xxxxxx
i-xxxxxx
i-xxxxxx
i-xxxxxx
etc etc
```

Comment: `client = boto3.client('ec2')` needs a region.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I thought the `RegionName` arg in the `get_sts_token` method would take care of that?

Comment: That's an entirely different client object, accessing a different service.

Comment: Looking more closely, I don't think `get_sts_token()`  is doing what you think it is, either.  You're calling it in void context and not actually using the value it returns... so you likely aren't even invoking `describe_instances()` on the correct accounts, because you aren't using the tokens.  `sts.assume_role()` does not change your identity.  It returns new credentials that you can use... but you have to actually use them.

Comment: Since the role arn is dynamic based on account number, how would I iterate over that and use the tokens for each boto3 ec2 call? That is the part I am struggling with.

Comment: You need to create a session/client object using the credentials you have obtained from assume_role API. Refer this: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004, I was able to pull the credentials from the API response and add them to my Session profile and it worked. Thanks. Maybe answer the question below so you can get credit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Michael - sqlbot mentioned, you are not using the token generated by the assume_role API call. Create your EC2 client object using the credentials obtained. Replace `get_sts_token(RoleArn=role_arn, RegionName="us-east-1")` line in your code with the following lines to retrieve the temporary credentials and use it to list the instances:

```
credentials = get_sts_token(RoleArn=role_arn, RegionName="us-east-1")
access_key = credentials['AccessKeyId']
secret_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey']
token = credentials['SessionToken']
session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    aws_session_token=token
)
client = session.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
response = client.describe_instances()
print(response)
```

This will return all the instances in us-east-1. If you need the list of instances in all regions, call describe_regions API and iterate through the list.

References:

- Documentation about Session object can be found [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html).

Answer (score -1):

The output of `print(response)` is correct.

However you can try this to get your desired output:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
instances = ec2.instance.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
'Values' ": ['running']}])
for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)
```